# How To Provide a "Customer Survey" Option on a Custom Version of WooCommerce "Thank You" Page

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

The general idea is to allow the customer, on a `custom thank you page`, to provide feedback. That feedback is then stored as a `customer note` on the order.

What I CANNOT figure out is what hook to use to make the survey visible on the new "Thank You" page? IF anyone knows, please let me know.

This did work, but now - after having changed the URL of the "`Thank You`" page, it does not. Perhaps that is because I am using the wrong `action hook` or perhaps of something else?

From the beginning, I used (after searching online, finding and modifying), that I can use the `template_redirect` hook and that way, set a custom "Thank You" page.

**So, here it is:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'survey_on_thank_you', 999, 2 );
function survey_on_thank_you( $order_id, $wp ) {

    // I DO NOT KNOW IF I NEED ANT OF THESE?
    /*
    global $wp;
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) && isset( $wp->query_vars[ 'order-received' ] ) 
    && absint( $wp->query_vars[ 'order-received' ] ) > 0 ) {
    $order_id = absint( $wp->query_vars[ 'order-received' ] ) ;
    */

    // set the URL for the "Thank You" page
    $order_received = home_url( '/thanks-for-ordering/' ) . '?order_id=' . $order_id;

    // check that we are on that page    
    if ( is_page( $order_received ) ) {

        // start the survey process

        echo '<br>';
        echo '<div class="survey-section">';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<h2 class="experience-title">How was your experience with us today?</h2>';
        echo '<p class="experience-options">Please choose below (and please be honest)</p>';
        
        echo '<form id="thank_you_survey_form">
            <label class="survey-questions"><input type="radio" name="like" value="AWESOME"> AWESOME </label>
            <label class="survey-questions"><input type="radio" name="like" value="VERY GOOD"> VERY GOOD </label>
            <label class="survey-questions"><input type="radio" name="like" value="NEUTRAL"> NEUTRAL </label>
            <label class="survey-questions"><input type="radio" name="like" value="IMPROVEMENT"> CAN BE IMPROVED </label>
            <label class="survey-questions"><input type="radio" name="like" value="POOR"> POOR </label>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="collect_feedback" />
            <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="' . $order_id . '" />
            ' . wp_nonce_field( 'thankyou'.$order_id, 'thankyou_nonce', true, false ) . ' </form>';

            // now continue with the layout
            echo '<br>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

**Step two is displaying the option result:**

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'submit_survvey_form' );
function submit_survvey_form() {

    // make sure this actually is the "order received" page, aka: Thank You 
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) return;

    // if it is, use the jQuery to add the anser as a customer order note
    echo "<script>

            jQuery( function($) {
            $( 'input[type=radio][name=like]' ).change( function() {
        
                $.ajax( {
                url: '" . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . "',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $( '#survey_form' ).serialize(),
                beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
        
                $( ' #survey_form ' ).html ( '<h3>Thank you! Your feedback means everything to us!<br/>
                Without you, we would be nothing.</h3> ' );
            },
        
                success : function( data ) {
                // not sure logging it as a console log is needed?
                console.log( data );
             }
         );
     }
);

     });
     </script>";
}
```

**Step 3 is to add the answer as a customer note on the order**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_collect_feedback', 'collect_survvey_form_feedback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_collect_feedback', 'collect_survvey_form_feedback' );
function collect_survvey_form_feedback() {

        // make sure it's done
        check_ajax_referer( 'thankyou'.$_POST[ 'order_id' ], 'thankyou_nonce' );

        if ( $order = wc_get_order( $_POST[ 'order_id' ] ) ) {
        
            $note = $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() . '  answered: <b>' . $_POST[ 'like' ] . '</b> . ';

                $order->add_order_note( $note, 0, true );
            }
    die();
}
```